# What is @OneToOne mapping in spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am new to Spring data jpa and trying to understand @OneToOne mapping.
Let's say I have a Employee entity and a Company Entity, If I want to map these 2 entities, then I can use one to one mapping on Employee entity which means one employee can belong to one company only.
Is this understanding wrong?
If one employee belongs to one company(lets say XYZ) then the company(XYZ) cannot be mapped to a different employee?

I have read few posts but not completely understood.

Comment: One-to-one is bi-directional. Company/Employee is one-to-many (everybody works for a single company) or many-to-many (some people have second jobs).

Comment: May help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one_(data_model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say an employee can be mapped to a Company that is one to one mapping keeping Employee as owner of the relationship. Whereas if you view Company as owner of the relationship, that it is One to Many.

```
Case 1 : Employee as Owner

@Entity
Public class Employee
{
  @ManyToOne
  private Company company;
 ......
}

@Entity
Public class Company
{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="company") \\ mappedBy is used to say that Employee is owner and 
                               \\it should match variable name company
  private List<Employee> employee;
  ......
}
```

Comment: Lets say employee ABC is mapped to a company XYZ then employee DEF can never be mapped to a company XYZ as this @OneToOne Mapping?

Comment: Employee DEF, PQR, STG any number of Employees can also be mapped to Company XYZ.

Comment: It should be @ManyToOne in Employee Class. I have corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I got your point but what I am trying to figure out is in case of OneToOne, one employee XYZ is mapped to one company ABC and then employee DEF can never be mapped to company ABC as company ABC already has been mapped to employee XYZ, am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Thats correct only if you put @OneToOne in Company Class for Employee.

Answer (score 1):

@OneToOne represents that there is only one Object of Entity related to the other Entity
if we have Employee and Passport Entity so only One Passport related to One Employee
and for sure one One Object of Employee related to One Object from Passport

```
@Entity
Public class Employee
{
      @OneToOne
      private Passport passport;
}
```

so from Employee i can get his Passport

```
@Entity
Public class Passport
{
      @OneToOne
      private Employee employee;
}
```

and from Passport i can get The Employee.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping is nothing but defining the relationship between two entities/objects and it is just like stating 5>4, 10=10, 6<8. The numbers here (5,4,10,6 and 8) are the entities and the symbols (>, = and <) are the relationships/mapping between them.
We do the same with mappings in hibernate. Note down the two entities and put in between them the relationship (mapping) them in the way it makes more sense.

Father OneToMany Child  (Father **can be One, To Many** child/children)

Child ManyToOne Father (Child/Children **can be Many, To One** Father)

Employee ManyToOne Company (Employee **can be Many, To One** Company)

Company OneToMany Employees (Company **can be One, To Many** Employee(s))

Address OneToOne Employee (Address **can be One, To One** Employee)

Employee OneToOne Address (Employee **can be One, To One** Address)

The relationship should make sense. Which means it should make sense when you look at the relationship from each of the both sides of the relationships (One child Many Fathers doesnt make sense but One Father many child/children does)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.

If you want the Company to have multiple Employees, then you want a ManyToOne relationship between Employee and Company, and a OneToMany relationship between the Company and employee.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in this case, You must use one to many relationship.
you can simply use the @ManytoOne annotation in Company Entity that related to Employee Entity.

> Specifies a single-valued association to another entity class that has many-to-one multiplicity. It is not normally necessary to specify the target entity explicitly since it can usually be inferred from the type of the object being referenced. If the relationship is bidirectional, the non-owning OneToMany entity side must used the mappedBy element to specify the relationship field or property of the entity that is the owner of the relationship.

Visit https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne for more information and samples.